# Pandas read_csv() with one row of data returns Empty Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with one row of data with no header. Below is my code for importing data into a dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(path2, header=0)
```

When I do read_csv it returns the following:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0.940456, 0.077893, 0.840178, 0.668612, 0.923643, 0.641833, 0.845249, 0.361605, 0.453943, 0.695509, 0.825763, 0.503687, 0.617303, 0.276637, 0.636244, 0.075744]
Index: []
```

df2.info() returns the following:

```
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 16 columns):
0.940456    0 non-null object
...
```

How do I set the first row as row instead of columns?

Comment: Is it the same when using `header=None`?

Comment: **rows**, you mean index or data part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means first row is converted to columns names, need `header=None` for default columns names with data in first row of `DataFrame`:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(path2, header=None)
```

Comment: The default behavior for `pd.read_csv()` is `header=0` which means that the first line will be considered as column names while `header=None` will not take the first row as columns as indicated in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).